# Linking a .s file with CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake, icc, ros

I have a c function that I'd like to use but thats compiled with the `Intel` compiler instead of the `gnu` `C` compiler. I'm using `cmake` to build the program.
(I'm actually using `ROS` and hence `rosmake` but the base is `cmake` so I think its more of a cmake issue than a `ROS` issue). 
Suppose the file built with `icc` is `x.c` and produces an `x.s` file. I want to use the function `a()` from `x.c` in my file `y.cpp`. 
In `y.cpp` I have:

```
#include "x.h" 
..... 
call a()
```

which works if `CMakeLists.txt` has

```
rosbuild_add_executable(y y.cpp x.c)

rosbuild_add_executable is analogous to add_executable(...)
```

but if I build `x.c` with `icc` and try to include the `x.s` file instead:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(y y.cpp x.s)
```

It doesnt work. Is there some change I should make to the way I call `a()` in `y.cpp`? or is there some other way to link it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using gcc, you can compile `.S` files with your C compiler (no explicit invocation of asm needed). CMake can be told to do so using

```
set_property(SOURCE <myfile>.S PROPERTY LANGUAGE C)
```

for each of your `.S` files.

Comment: do you know of a way to associate S files with gcc in general? 
Like in makefile it would be smth along
.S.o:
 $(CROSS_COMPILER)gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

Answer (score 4):

To work with `.s` files you'll have to enable assembly language support in CMake with `enable_language`.

You can find more information here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/languages/Assembler

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume. From that I assumed that I have to enable the corresponding assembler language and then just simply link the file in the executable. but I'm really sure I'm missing something here. Is there something I should be doing in the .cpp file ?

Comment: @canatan Enabling the language and adding the `.s` file to your `add_executable` call should be enough. The only thing I'm not sure about is if CMake supports the Intel assembly language / compiler as the only two languages in the doc are ASM-ATT and ASM_MASM.

Comment: a colleague looked at the .s file and said that its ASM-ATT .. when I do a simple linkage it gives me the following error which i'm assuming is specific to ROS 
> /usr/bin/as: unrecognized option '->OS_PACKAGE_NAME="landshark_dwaICCIntegration"'

Comment: that's weird... are you sure you're not setting that `OS_PACKAGE_NAME` somewhere in your CMakeLists?

Comment: I'm using ROS which uses rosbuild which I think uses CMAKE http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples .. I think its a ROS thing ..

Comment: well... I don't think so... asking google about OS_PACKAGE_NAME only return the same question you asked on aswners.ros.org